# Dataframe did not insert into DB but throws DPI Not connected error

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I need to insert a dataframe into oracle sql and fastest method I could found was sqlalchemy but this doesn't seem to work in my favor.

My code :

```
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import types
import cx_Oracle

DIALECT = 'oracle'
SQL_DRIVER = 'cx_oracle'
USERNAME = 'NCSWEB' #enter your username
PASSWORD = '########' #enter your password
HOST = '192.168.213.151' #enter the oracle db host url
PORT = 1515 # enter the oracle port number
SERVICE = 'devnc12c' # enter the oracle db service name
ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD +'@' + HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/?service_name=' + SERVICE

engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH)
print(engine)
#read data from csv
fileName='C:\\Users\\ncdex1124\Desktop\\New folder\\file4.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
print(df)
dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(df[c].str.len().max())
    for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}
try:
    df.to_sql('UCIDBA.FUT_CLIENT_LIST_COPY', engine.connect(), if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000,dtype=dtyp)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
print("Record inserted successfully")
```

Output:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1751, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\oracle\cx_oracle.py", line 1347, in do_executemany        
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1080: connection was closed by ORA-3135

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1866, in _safe_close_cursor
    cursor.close()
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1010: not connected
(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1010: not connected
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

I dont understand what is wrong in this case .

Comment: Two comments: (1) since you have a CSV file use SQL*Loader for best performance, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/a/69090794/4799035  (2) If you want to continue with Python then review using cx_Oracle's `executeMany()` function directly so you have control over error handling, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html which has a CSV example

Answer (score 1):

By default, `cx_oracle` rollbacks any transaction without explicit commit.

> **Autocommitting mode**
>
> The Connection object has an attribute called
> **autocommit** that allows you to commit the transaction automatically. By
> default, its value sets to False. To instruct cx_Oracle commit the
> transaction automatically, you set the value of the
> Connection.autocommit to True as follows:
>
> **connection.autocommit = True**

As you are using Pandas and `create_engine` from `SQL Alchemy`, you need to

```
connection = engine.connect()
connection = connection.execution_options(
    isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT"
)
```

Regarding your code, I would try this, keeping in consideration that you are using latest version of `Pandas` and `Sql Alchemy`. It should work.

```
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import types
import cx_Oracle
DIALECT = 'oracle'
SQL_DRIVER = 'cx_oracle'
USERNAME = 'NCSWEB' #enter your username
PASSWORD = '########' #enter your password
HOST = '192.168.213.151' #enter the oracle db host url
PORT = 1515 # enter the oracle port number
SERVICE = 'devnc12c' # enter the oracle db service name
ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD +'@' + HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/?service_name=' + SERVICE

engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH,max_identifier_length=128)
print(engine)
#read data from csv
fileName='C:\\Users\\ncdex1124\Desktop\\New folder\\file4.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
print(df)
dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(df[c].str.len().max())
    for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}
try:
    engine = engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True) 
    df.to_sql('UCIDBA.FUT_CLIENT_LIST_COPY', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000,dtype=dtyp)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
print("Record inserted successfully")
```

An example how it works the connection with autocommit on my own enviroment

```
C:\python>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
>>> from sqlalchemy import types
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>> DIALECT = 'oracle'
>>> SQL_DRIVER = 'cx_oracle'
>>> USERNAME = 'PYTHON' #enter your username
>>> PASSWORD = '#######' #enter your password
>>> HOST = 'ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP' #enter the oracle db host url
>>> PORT = 60995 # enter the oracle port number
>>> SERVICE = 'odcgrc1r' # enter the oracle db service name
>>> ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD +'@' + HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/?service_name=' + SERVICE
>>> engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH,max_identifier_length=128)
>>> print(engine)
Engine(oracle+cx_oracle://PYTHON:***@ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP:60995/?service_name=odcgrc1r)
>>> #read data from csv
>>> engine = engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True)
>>>
```

Comment: I added this snippet at the end of my code but still same case . can u please help me where it will be added in my code or is there anything else that needs to be done ??

Comment: give me a bit and will give you a version of the code that should work

Comment: Thank you for the help !! I am really stuck up in trying to insert dataframe faster in  Oracle DB

Comment: A nice way to say thank you is to upvote the answer.

Comment: @AlokSharma, put your results in your question, using the edit option, not as an answer. Run the program line by line, as I did with my example. We will see in which line we have the problem. Perhaps the issue is in `Pandas` and not in `SQL Alchemy`. I would appreciate if you upvote the answer. Thank you

Comment: Updated my question . I did debug and exeception occured in df.to_sql part. is this because all my dataframes columns are varchar while in db there are few date datatype as well ?  Posted another question with more details                                                                                          [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69083229/dpi-1010-not-connected-error-when-inserting-into-oracle-db

Comment: @AlokSharma, you are using `dtype=dtyp` , which means that whatever is in the excel will be interpreted as such.  If the problem is with `date` datatype, I suggess to use `dtype={'date_appended': sqlalchemy.Date()}`