# DPI-1010: not connected Error When Inserting into Oracle DB

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to insert dataframe into a table .Is there any other way to fast insert dataframe into  DB Table having Various datatypes.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import types
import cx_Oracle
DIALECT = 'oracle'
SQL_DRIVER = 'cx_oracle'
USERNAME = 'NCSWEB' #enter your username
PASSWORD = '#####' #enter your password
HOST = '192.168.213.151' #enter the oracle db host url
PORT = 1515 # enter the oracle port number
SERVICE = 'devnc12c' # enter the oracle db service name
ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD +'@' + HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/?service_name=' + SERVICE

engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH,max_identifier_length=128)
print(engine)
#read data from csv
fileName='C:\\Users\\ncdex1124\Desktop\\New folder\\file4.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
print(df)
dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(df[c].str.len().max())
    for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}
try:
    engine = engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True) 
    df.to_sql('UCIDBA.FUT_CLIENT_LIST_COPY', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000,dtype=dtyp)
    print("Record inserted successfully")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

While Executing The above Script I am Getting Following Error

```
    PS C:\Users\ncdex1124> & C:/Users/ncdex1124/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe D:\test\insertcsvscript.py
Engine(oracle+cx_oracle://NCSWEB:***@192.168.213.151:1515/?service_name=devnc12c)
         CL_SEQ  CL_TMID CL_CLIENT_ID      CL_PAN CL_CLI_STATUS CL_PAN_STATUS  CL_ACTION_TYPE  CL_CREATED_DATE CL_CREATED_BY CL_MODIFIED_DATE CL_MODIFIED_BY
0       3793375       21      MEN0008  ARJPP6330Q             A            V                0   9/6/2019 14:23        SYSTEM   9/9/2019 11:28         SYSTEM
1       3793378        8   AACCB1987D  AACCB1987D             A            V                0   9/7/2019 14:23        SYSTEM  9/10/2019 11:28         SYSTEM
2       3793381       10   AABCI2081G  AABCI2081G             A            V                0   9/8/2019 14:23        SYSTEM  9/11/2019 11:28         SYSTEM
3       3793383       11   AABCN9894G  AABCN9894G             A            V                0   9/9/2019 14:23        SYSTEM  9/12/2019 11:28         SYSTEM
4       3793387       12   AAACM0267F  AAACM0267F             A            V                0  9/10/2019 14:23        SYSTEM  9/13/2019 11:28         SYSTEM
...         ...      ...          ...         ...           ...           ...             ...              ...           ...              ...            ...
180011  3793368      185   AACCC0537F  AACCC0537F             A            V                0  7/14/2512 14:23        SYSTEM   9/6/2019 14:24         SYSTEM
180012  3793369      161   AAACP7015P  AAACP7015P             A            V                0  7/15/2512 14:23        SYSTEM   9/6/2019 14:24         SYSTEM
180013  3793370      159   AAACA8392E  AAACA8392E             A            V                0  7/16/2512 14:23        SYSTEM   9/6/2019 14:24         SYSTEM
180014  3793371      167   AACCC5501F  AACCC5501F             A            V                0  7/17/2512 14:23        SYSTEM   9/6/2019 14:24         SYSTEM
180015  3793372      168   AAHCS7515E  AAHCS7515E             A            V                0  7/18/2512 14:23        SYSTEM   9/6/2019 14:24         SYSTEM

[180016 rows x 11 columns]
Error closing cursor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1751, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\oracle\cx_oracle.py", line 1347, in do_executemany        
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1080: connection was closed by ORA-3135

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1866, in _safe_close_cursor
    cursor.close()
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1010: not connected
(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1010: not connected
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

The DB Table Structure looks like this

```
CL_SEQ             NUMBER
CL_TMID            VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
CL_CLIENT_ID       VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
CL_PAN             VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
CL_CLI_STATUS      CHAR(1 BYTE)
CL_PAN_STATUS      CHAR(2 BYTE)
CL_ACTION_TYPE     VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
CL_CREATED_DATE    DATE
CL_CREATED_BY      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
CL_MODIFIED_DATE   DATE
CL_MODIFIED_BY     VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
```

What am I doing wrong here .Or Is there any other way ?