# Load huge csv file into oracle database table using Pyspark

Tags: python, oracle, pyspark

Currently I am using `Python` to connect to `RESTAPI` and extracting huge volume of data in csv file. The number of rows are almost `80 million`. Now i want to load this huge data into `Oracle` database table. I tried to load using `sql loader` and also `ODI` tool but it was taking hours to load this data.

I want to try with `Pyspark` as its good for loading large datasets. But as i am new to `Pyspark` not sure as a first approach will it be performance efficient to load such huge csv into oracle database table ?
As second approach will it be performance efficient if instead of creating csv file just store the data from `RESTAPI` in memory and load into database table ?

Which approach will be better ?

Below is how my CSV data looks like
[image]

Comment: From my point of view, SQL*Loader is really, really fast. I would use it. Maybe control file you used isn't "optimal"? On the other hand, 80 million rows is quite a lot of data, it takes time to load. Have a look at this: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/10/yes-sqlloader-is-faster-at-loading-records/

Comment: You want to use a `direct path` load, not the *conventional* load for you data size. See SQL*Loader [docu](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-conventional-and-direct-loads.html#GUID-321928FB-C86C-4F1F-9250-05111A988B7B)

Comment: How about using Pyspark ? I will try with sql-loader again..but i want to run the sql loader from command propt for example and not via sql developer tool

Comment: SQL Loader is much faster than Pyspark, if it is properly configured.

Comment: can you provide the control file you are using for SQL Loader ? I assure you ( I tested both ) and SQL Loader is much faster.

Comment: _" run the sql loader from command propt for example and not via sql developer tool "_   sqlldr _is_ a command-line tool.  SQL DEv is just a GUI that will call it for you.  But it is still a command-line tool, that can be called directly from the command line, or from a command or shell script.  Before you reject  it out of hand, you need to spend some quality time with the actual documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144

Comment: thanks all...would be really helpful if i get one example here for example i am generating report.csv which i want to load in oracle database table...so do i need to provide all the field from csv as well as database table and will the name of columns from csv and databse should be same ?  I will check the documentation and try to check the direct path approach from sql loader...

Comment: if i have for example multiple files then i cannot apply loop in sql loader ? i also tried with ODI tool which works same like sql loader but its very slow with this...

Comment: yes , you can. You can use `wildcards` for referring to different files to be loaded in a single table, as long as all those files are targeting the same table.

Comment: @Andrew, I can provide you an example of a control file for sql loader with parameters for loading as fast as possible. Let me know if you want it.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez it will be really helpful if you can provide an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me show you an example of a control file I use to load a very big file ( 120 Million records each day )

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=0, ERRORS=500, PARALLEL=TRUE, MULTITHREADING=TRUE, DIRECT=TRUE, SILENT=(ALL))
UNRECOVERABLE
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1
INFILE '/path_to_your_file/name_of_the_file.txt'
BADFILE '/path_to_your_file/name_of_the_file.bad'
DISCARDFILE '/path_to_your_file/name_of_the_file.dsc'
APPEND
INTO TABLE yourtablename
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
COLUMN1 POSITION(1:4) CHAR
,COLUMN2 POSITION(5:8)  CHAR
,COLUMN3 POSITION(9:11) CHAR
,COLUMN4 POSITION(12:18) CHAR
....
....)
```

Some considerations

- It is always faster loading by positions than using delimiters
- Use the options of `PARALLEL`, `MULTITHREADING` and `DIRECT` to optimize loading performace.
- `UNRECOVERABLE` is also a good advice if you always have the file in case you need to recover the database, you'd need to load the data again.
- Use the appropriate characterset.
- The TRAILING NULLCOLS clause tells SQL*Loader to treat any relatively positioned columns that are not present in the record as null columns.
- Position means that each row contains data without any delimiter, so you know the position of each field in the table by the length.

`AAAAABBBBBBCCCCC19828733UUUU`

- If your txt or csv file has a field separator, let's say semicolon, then you need to use the `FIELDS DELIMITED BY`

This is stored in a control file, normally a text file with extension ctl. Then you invoke from command line

```
sqlldr userid=youuser/pwd@tns_string control=/path_to_control_file/control_file.ctl
```

Comment: i dont understand about TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
CONTRACT POSITION(1:4) CHAR
,CENTER POSITION(5:8)  CHAR
,PRODUCT_CODE POSITION(9:11) CHAR
,ACCOUNT POSITION(12:18) CHAR

Comment: Is it the position of your text file content ? In my csv how it works ? I also want to exclude few fields from the csv file how to do this ?

Comment: I updated the answer with your questions answered.

Comment: the section of CONTRACT, CENTER is regarding the columns you want to load in your table

Comment: thanks very much i tried to load more than 1 billion records into database table using sql loader and it just took 11sec ...i dont know why it took time from ODI because ODI tool is from oracle for loading purpose.. and it also use the same approach like SQL loader....one question which database you use to load such huge data ? I am not sure for such Big Data Oracle database is good because i want to keep history and the records will grow ...

Comment: Maybe you need to tune ODI?  Either way, SQL*Loader is _the_ Oracle DB tool for loading data.

Comment: @Andrew, if the records will grow in time on the table you want to load to, then you should think on Partitioning. I have a DB of 40TB, one of the interfaces loads 120m each day, but the table where the data is loaded is partitioned by day, so the batch only uses the specific partition. However, if you want to use SQL Analytics to get data reporting based on months or days, or even years, it can be done, but that explanation will need an article to show you how to do it in the best possible way and with the best performance.

Comment: @Andrew, by the way, ODI is a ETL tool designed for not loading, but for transformation. It is like Informatica Powercenter. But even in ODI you can use SQL Loader for the loading part itself. ODI is a tool for very different purposes ( mappings, workflows, etc) . SQL Loader is just a loading tool, the best I can think of for Oracle.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez yes i think i will use ODI just to call sql loader shell script...For partition can you please suggest any article..actually we want to load such billions of data everyday and also would like to create reports based on this huge data...

Comment: @Andrew, I'd start by this https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/

Comment: two key parts : Partitioning and Parallel Execution. They are the two masters ;)